# What does External_threads_connected mean in Aurora MySQL 5.6.10

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

We have 3000 limits for max connection using RDS db.r4.2xlarge, but when our application utilizes 2000 connection we got an error in our application  **Too many connections** which is quite amazing to me, but When I run query this query `show status like '%onn%';`

I got a response having something like

> 'External_threads_connected', '1102'

we are using AWS cluster with reader and writer.
Do I need to consider this value in my active connection or does this value contributing to the max connection?